# calculate the harmonic mean and geometric mean without exceeding double max value?

Tags: c#, .net, statistics, mean, geometric-mean

For a vector (set of numbers) whose multiplication or division would exceed the minimum or maximum value of type double and/or decimal, how could the geometric mean and harmonic mean be calculated?

Any existing implementation I have found did not make this consideration (i.e. they could calculate a small set, but not a large set).

Comment: If perfomance is important, you can look for ideas in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19980319/5311735. It's C++, but problem is the same, and double behaves the same in C++ and C#.

Comment: @Evk thanks for that link.  It is very helpful.  I will try to port that method to c#.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to multiply numbers of any size (e.g. bigger than any MaxValue) by representing them as strings, and writing a method to calculate the result.

If you did "long multiplication" in school, that is the algorithm to follow, just calculating one digit at a time and working your way along from least significant digit to most significant.

Similarly, you can do division of these string based numbers by writing a method to do "long division". You can build a method for geometric mean based on those. I don't know about "harmonic mean"s... but I'm hoping that would also be solvable at that point.

Hope this helps.